# SQL User Defined Variables as an SQL Query

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to create a dynamic html table that is comprised of data from 2 tables in an sql database. One table in the db will hold model names, user's ratings of those models, and their IP address to limit ratings per IP. The other table will hold information about the models, such as age, location, etc. To do this I was thinking on using an inner join so that the ratings from table1 match up with the correct person(s) info from table2. I'm pretty new to all of this, but from what I've read it does not seem like I would be able to have an sql user defined variable as a query. Since the table which holds the ratings will have multiple entries for each model with different ratings, I am trying to work it out so that the rating which shows in my html table will be the avg rating for that model. My first question is just to confirm that SQL User Defined Variables cannot be an SQL query? If not, what other method could I use to have sort of a query inside of an inner join query?

This works, but not exactly what I want:

```
$query = "SELECT table2.Rating, table2.Model, table1.Age, table1.Country
                        FROM table1
                        INNER JOIN table2
                        ON table2.Model= table1.Model
                        ORDER BY table2.Rating DESC
                        LIMIT 5";

$query5 = mysqli_query($link, $query);              



echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Rating</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Country</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query5))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Rating'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

I'd like for 'Model' in the inner join above to actually be DISTINCT, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Model FROM Table2";

    $run = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

And for 'Rating' to be AVG('Rating') like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM Table2';

$quit = mysqli_query($link, $query);

            $run = mysqli_fetch_array($quit);
```

Comment: Sorry, meant to update... teen2 = table2. Table2 will hold user's ratings, model names, and collect ip addresses. Table1 will just hold basic info on models like location etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a summary of the raw `table2`, like so:

```
 SELECT Model, AVG(Rating)
   FROM table2
  GROUP BY Model
```

If I understand your table structure adequately, that gives you a result set containing each model and its average rating.  So now you use that in your main query, in place of your raw table2. It works like this:

```
SELECT a.Rating, 
       a.Model, 
       table1.Age, table1.Country
  FROM table1
 INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Model, 
                   AVG(Rating) AS Rating
             FROM table2
            GROUP BY Model

            ) AS a ON a.Model= table1.Model
 ORDER BY a.Rating DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

The trick here is to put the *Structured* in *Structured Query Language* by realizing that you can use a virtual table, also known as a subquery, anyplace you can use a table.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you explain how the 'a.Rating' and 'a.Model' work? Could you elaborate more on how subqueries work? It looks like you understand what I'm trying to do but being a newbie I'm having a hard time understanding haha